# React 16.2 <Fragment> gives Uncaught error: Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I just updated to react 16.2 and I want to use the cool Fragment feature. However I get strange error as soon as just use it in a simple way:

```
<React.Fragment>asd</React.Fragment>
```

The error states: Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.

When I log the above code and just a random component I have defined I get this information:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {children: "asd"}
ref: null
type: Symbol(react.fragment)
...
```

When I log my element I get the almost same information:

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {children: "sfdghs"}
ref: null
type:ƒ Column(_ref)
```

My question is: why does the app expect string or function.

All related dependancies from my package.json are as such:

- `"devDependencies": {... "@types/react": "^16.0.0" ...}`
- `"dependencies" : {... "react": "^16.2.0", "typescript": "2.6.2" ...}`

If anyone can give me any information on how to debug this, I will be very grateful!

Comment: a simpler syntax this also works fine: `<>some content</>`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need a **minimum** of `16.2.0` for both `react` & `react-dom`.

Comment: @brianmearns make sure you've updated **both** `react` and `react-dom` libraries. Above solved the issue for me, when I forgot to update `react-dom` as well.

Comment: @brianmearns, try restarting your dev server.

Comment: @EugeneKulabuhov I'm not doing live-loading, the server is rebuilt and restarted every time I run. Thanks anyway.